# Spring data mongo aggregation with @Field annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have requirement to perform group by on nested fields in mongo.
The second level nested field is annotated with @Field. I am using projection with groupBy.
Example

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("id")
            .and("author.eid").as("user");
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group(aggregationBy, "user").count().as("total");
Aggregation aggregation =
        Aggregation.newAggregation(projectionOperation groupOperation);
AggregationResults<Document> aggregationResults = myRepository.getMongoTemplate().aggregate(aggregation, MyClass.class, Document.class);
```

On execution I am getting error "**org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property eid found for type User!**"

```
public class MyClass {
 User author;
}
public class User {
 @Field("eid")
 @JsonProperty("eid") // fasterxml
 public String externalId;
}
```

What I can think of is when casting the aggregation result to MyClass, it is unable to find "eid" because it is annotated.

How to handle this usecase ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Field` annotation parsed to replace the pojo property with the field name.

So you should be using

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("id")
            .and("author.externalId").as("user");
```

the query generated will be

```
{ "$project" : { "user" : "$author.eid" }
```